# How can I set up a sql development server with python?

Tags: python, sql-server, database, localhost

TLDR: Im looking for a way to get started with SQL data management in Python.

I'm looking to get into SQL and database management with python, I have some experience in other languages but I have only done some basic programming with python. I want to learn about managing data using python and SQL databases, I have pycharm installed and setup as well as anaconda, git and and a microsoft 2019 development server but I can't figure out how to connect them into a workflow and get started with some actual code.
Does anyone have any tips on how to get started? I would prefer a free solution or keeping it as cheap as possible. Preferably locally hosted.

Comment: Any specific SQL database in mind? There are dozens of them, perhaps you meant MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yeah, so far I've been trying to setup a microsoft SQL server